# Iframe within iframe - Is there a direct connection? PCI-DSS q

Tags: html, iframe, pci-dss

Theory question please.

Site 'A', contains an iframe to domain 'B', the html hosted on domain 'B' in turn has an iframe to domain 'C'.

A user is browsing site 'A'.  Do they have a direct connection to domain 'C' or is their connection via the iframe hosted on domain 'B'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they have a connection to A, B and C as its their browser that requests all the pages from all three domains, based on the iframe source urls.

Transactions via an iframe & an intermediate are specifically covered [here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/PCI_DSS_v2_eCommerce_Guidelines.pdf).

> In this implementation, the merchant should consider both third
>   parties—the intermediate party hosting the iFrame and the third party
>   processor who provides the iFrame—to be service providers for the
>   merchant, and the merchant should monitor the PCI DSS compliance of
>   both third parties.